# Use variables declared in the webpack config inside js file

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have added some varaibles inside my webpack.config.js file like this

```
module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

     
          {
            test: lessRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders(
              {
                importLoaders: 2,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                javascriptEnabled: true
              },
              'less-loader',
              {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                modifyVars: { '@primary-color': '#5cb885','@secondary-color':'#2e3456' }
              }
            )
          }
        ]
      }
```

so in css file i can use them via

```
index.less

.mainText {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: @primary-color;
}
```

But how can i use this variable in my jsx file if suppose i want to give inline styling for any element ?

Answer (score 1):

In your webpack file you can declare any variable like this ->

```
module.exports = {
externals: {
        'config': JSON.stringify({ EXP_TIME: new Date() })
    },
    modules : [...],
```

Then in any JS file you can simply import like this ->

```
var config = require('config')
var tokenExpTime = config.EXP_TIME
console.log(tokenExpTime)    //Will print current date and time
```

Hope you got the point now. :)